# How to separate a series of objects from the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reduce, use-reducer

I'm using a **useReducer**  And this is what I have:

```
const initialState = {
    optionalFilter: {
      take: Math.round((window.innerHeight - 330) / 34),
      page: 1,
    },
    reportFilter: {
      searchItem:[],
      dateFilter: {
        StartDate:new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3100)),
        EndDate:new Date(),
      },
     
    }, 
  };
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "changeFilter":
        console.log("action",action.payload)
        return updateObject(state, {
          optionalFilter: updateObject(state.optionalFilter, {
            page: 1,
          }),
          reportFilter: updateObject(state.reportFilter, {
            searchItem: action.payload,
          }),
          reportFilter: updateObject(state.reportFilter.dateFilter, {
            StartDate:new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 3100)),
        EndDate:new Date(),
          }),
        });
    }
  };
```

When I want to apply filler .For example, when I get a console of action, I have such an array:

> console of action.payload==>[{property:"StartDate: ,
> value:"12.12.12"}{property:"EndDate: ,
> value:"13.13.12"}{property:"Title: , value:"test"}{property:"name": ,
> value:"name"}]

How should I have the StartDate and EndDate values in **state.reportFilter.dateFilter** And put the rest of the values in the **searchItem** array

Comment: to be able to delete from an object add --- delete myObject.StartDate

Comment: to add new data to the object just do myObject['newobject'] = "hello"

Comment: can you show what is updateObject function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code by replacing the reducer method

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "changeFilter":
        console.log("action",action.payload)
        return updateObject(state, {
          optionalFilter: updateObject(state.optionalFilter, {
            page: 1,
          }),
          reportFilter: updateObject(state.reportFilter, {
            searchItem: action.payload.filter(val => val.property !== "StartDate" &&  val.property !== "EndDate");,
          }),
          reportFilter: updateObject(state.reportFilter.dateFilter, {
            StartDate:action.payload.find(val => val.property === "StartDate").value,
        EndDate:action.payload.find(val => val.property === "EndDate").value,
          }),
        });
    }
  };
```